# SystemIO: The process cannot access the file X because it is used by another process (same process)

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous, io

I'm getting the error `The process cannot access the file X because it is used by another process` and I am pretty sure that it is the same process because I have checked every other app open.

These are the times I use this file.

```
...
string jsonString;
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(hardware);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + @"\HardwareInfo.json", jsonString);
// ^^ This is where I get the exception ^^
...
```

```
...
var uploadFile = path + @"\HardwareInfo.json";
    using (var localStream = File.OpenRead(uploadFile))
    {
        await client.UploadAsync(localStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadFile));
    }
...
```

I don't know if it matters but it is being used asynchronous in the second method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what Type is `client`? It looks to me like you are trying to read the file a second time when you call `UploadAsync`.

Comment: `var client = new SftpClient(host, int.Parse(port), username, password);` It's an SftpClient instance (SshNet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Without lock:

```
     using (var memStream = new MemoryStream) 
     {
        using (var localStream = File.OpenRead(uploadFile))
        {
            localStream.CopyTo(memStream);
        }

        await client.UploadAsync(memStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadFile));
     }
```

Comment: `cannot await in the body of a lock statement` I can't make the `client.UploadAsync` asynchronous.

Comment: @WoJo edit: problem is mostly because you are uploading  while file handle is open.

Comment: @Mertuarez This works, however the file on the SFTP Server is empty, and the one on my computer is not empty.

Comment: This is not bullet proof. So count on that your app will start consume more memory and in case of multiple read writes there will be clashes. Good choice is to create serviceclass with threadsafe read write methods. https://johandorper.com/log/thread-safe-file-writing-csharp or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8